# How can i add drag and drop functionality in ng2-smart table

Tags: ng2-smart-table

I have build a angular 7 application and using ng2-smart table to showing some records now i want to add drag and drop functionality in to this table so that i can drag the column or row from ng2-smart table and drop it to another table.
can anyone help me ?